# ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token

Tags: express, csrf

I am trying to use csrf in add employee function. However, whenever I hit submit I alway get ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token. I am not sure the way I did csrf correctly.

On the other hand, I have a login and register form. It works fine. And I did the same steps for add employee.

I've been reading some other posts but I didn't understand them. Can anyone point me to the correct way? I am really appreciate.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const {uploadProduct, uploadForEmployee, uploadForVendor} = require('../upload');
const validation = require('validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const csrf = require('csurf');

const csrfProtection = csrf();

//Load User model
const User = require('../../models/User');

router.get('/viewEmployee', (req, res) => {
User.find({$or: [{role: 'Admin'}, {role: 'Employee'}] }, (err, doc) => {
    res.status(200).render('./admin/viewEmployee', {
        user: req.user,
        doc: doc,
        link: "/admin/employees/"
    })
})
});

router.delete('/:email', (req, res) => {

User.deleteOne({email: req.params.email}, (err, user) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log('Error while deleting product');
    } else {
        console.log(req.params.email + ' deleted');
        res.redirect('/admin/employees/viewEmployee');
    }
});
});

router.use(csrfProtection);

router.get('/addEmployee', (req, res) => {
res.render("./admin/employeeForm", {csrfToken: req.csrfToken()});
});

router.post('/addEmployee', uploadForEmployee.single('image'), (req, res) => {
let {name, email, password, phone, address, role} = req.body;
let image = req.file;
let errors = [];

if(!name || !email || ! password || !phone || !address || !role) {
    errors.push({msg: 'Please enter all fields.'});
}

if(!image) {
    errors.push({msg: 'Please upload a photo of yourself.'});
}

//sanitize input
name = validation.escape(name);
email = validation.escape(email);
password = validation.escape(password);
phone = validation.escape(phone);
address = validation.escape(address);

//Validate email
if(!validation.isEmail(email)){
    errors.push({msg: 'Bad email.'})
} else {
    email = validation.normalizeEmail(email, [
    'all_lowercase', 'gmail_remove_dots','gmail_remove_subaddress', 'gmail_convert_googlemaildotcom', 
    'outlookdotcom_remove_subaddress', 'yahoo_remove_subaddress', 'icloud_remove_subaddress'
    ])
} 
if (password.length < 6) {
errors.push({ msg: 'Password must be at least 6 characters.' });
}

if (errors.length > 0) {
    res.render('./admin/employeeForm', {
        errors,
        name,
        email,
        password,
        phone,
        address,
        role,
        image,
        csrfToken: req.csrfToken()
    });
} else {
    User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {
        if (user) {
            errors.push({ msg: 'Email already exists.' });
            res.render('./admin/employeeForm', {
                errors,
                name,
                email,
                password,
                phone,
                address,
                role,
                image,
                csrfToken: req.csrfToken()
            });
        } else {
            const newUser = new User({
                name: name,
                email: email,
                password: password,
                phone: phone,
                address: address,
                role: role,
                imageUrl: '/images/employees/' + image.filename
            });

            bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
                bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    newUser.password = hash;
                    newUser
                    .save()
                    .then(user => {
                    req.flash(
                    'success_msg',
                    'You are now registered and can log in.'
                    );
                    res.redirect('/admin/employees/viewEmployee');
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
});


module.exports = router;
```

This is my login and register functions. These ones worked with csrf just fine.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const passport = require('passport');
const {ensureLoggedIn, ensureLoggedOut} = require('connect-ensure-login');
const validation = require('validator');
const csrf = require('csurf');

const csrfProtection = csrf();

// Load User model
const User = require('../models/User');

//Profile
router.get('/profile', ensureLoggedIn('/users/login'), (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('profile')
});

// Logout
router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  req.flash('success_msg', 'You are logged out.');
  res.redirect('/users/login');
});

// Register
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  let { name, email, password, password2 } = req.body;
  let errors = [];

  if (!name || !email || !password || !password2) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Please enter all fields' });
  }

  //sanitize input
  name = validation.escape(name);
  email = validation.escape(email);
  password = validation.escape(password);
  password2 = validation.escape(password2);

  //Validate email
  if(!validation.isEmail(email)){
    errors.push({msg: 'Bad email.'})
  } else {
    email = validation.normalizeEmail(email, [
      'all_lowercase', 'gmail_remove_dots','gmail_remove_subaddress', 'gmail_convert_googlemaildotcom', 
  'outlookdotcom_remove_subaddress', 'yahoo_remove_subaddress', 'icloud_remove_subaddress'
    ])
  } 

  if (password != password2) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Invalid Password.' });
  }

  if (password.length < 6) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Password must be at least 6 characters.' });
  }

  if (errors.length > 0) {
    res.render('./home/register', {
      errors,
      name,
      email,
      password,
      password2,
      csrfToken: req.csrfToken()
    });
  } else {
    User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {
      if (user) {
        errors.push({ msg: 'Email already exists.' });
        res.render('./home/register', {
          errors,
          name,
          email,
          password,
          password2,
          csrfToken: req.csrfToken()
        });
      } else {
        const newUser = new User({
          name,
          email,
          password
        });

        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
          bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser
              .save()
              .then(user => {
                req.flash(
                  'success_msg',
                  'You are now registered and can log in.'
                );
                res.redirect('/users/login');
              })
              .catch(err => console.log(err));
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
});

// Login
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successReturnToOrRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/users/login',
    failureFlash: true
  })(req, res, next);
});

router.use(csrfProtection);

// Login Page
router.get('/login', ensureLoggedOut('/'), (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('./home/login', {
    csrfToken: req.csrfToken()
  })
});

// Register Page
router.get('/register', ensureLoggedOut('/'), (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('./home/register', {
    csrfToken: req.csrfToken()
  })
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you